# iOS App - Long time exposure image

Tags: ios, edit, photo

Is there a way to create long time exposure app to take long exposure images? The maximum exposure time that you can set is 1 second in AVFoundation. Is there another way to do it like here: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/slow-shutter-cam/id357404131?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo%3D8

Comment: Are you using the `AVCaptureDevice setExposureModeCustomWithDuration:ISO:completionHandler:` method?

Comment: @rmaddy yes, I'm using that method, and the maximum exposure time is 1 sec..

Comment: The docs don't state a limit. Is the 1 second limit based on trying longer values and only getting 1 second at the most?

Comment: If you try to set values longer than 1s, the app crashes and it says that your value isn't in range. I know that the docs don't state a limit, but there is one... I wanna create long tine exposure images like 15s of exposure... @rmaddy

Answer (score 2):

Think around apple.

What is a long exposure shot? It's an image of several seconds worth of light data.

What if you just took several photos and combined them?

"Just stack the images and apply percent of opacity to the layer.

Lowest Layer: 100% Opacity

Second lowest layer  50% Opacity

Third lowest layer 33 % Opacity

and so on."

http://forum.luminous-landscape.com/index.php?topic=64233.0

Comment: I haven't looked but applying weights to images and then adding them may not be trivial.  in Photoshop and matlab this is easy to do.  ios???

Comment: it night be easier to pull in the opencv lib and build for ios.